# Почему функция ввода чисел в массив не выполняется?

Tags: javascript

Хочу наполнить массив и вывести его значение. 
Если выполнять оператор for вне функции, то всё работает. В функции же - нет.
Переменные объявлял и внутри функции и вне её, толка нет.
В чем причина невыполнения функции?

```
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<script>
    var c = parseInt(prompt("How much numbers do you want to put in the array? "));
    var arr1 = [];


    function fill_array(arr1){
        for (var i = 0; i < c; i++){
            var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number " + (i+1)));
            arr1.push(x);
            }   
        return arr1;
    }


    document_write(fill_array);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<script>
    var c = parseInt(prompt("How much numbers do you want to put in the array? "));
    var arr1 = [];

    function fill_array(arr1){
        for (var i = 0; i < c; i++){
            var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number " + (i+1)));
            arr1.push(x);
        }   
        return arr1;
    }

    document.write(fill_array(arr1));
</script>
```

У вас две ошибки:

1. Очевидно, `document_write` - ерунда полная. `document.write` - так верно.
2. В `document.write()` вы передаете саму функцию, а не результат ее работы. Чтобы передать результат выполнения функции, нужно ее вызвать. Т.е. так:

   ```
   document.write(fill_array(arr1));
   ```

Вот.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё предельно ясно!

Answer (score 0):

Вызвать же надо функцию. И что это за `document_write`?

```js
var c = parseInt(prompt("How much numbers do you want to put in the array? "));
var arr1 = [];


function fill_array(arr1) {
  for (var i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number " + (i + 1)));
    arr1.push(x);
  }
  return arr1;
}

document.write(fill_array(arr1));
```

Comment: Исправил ошибку, но к сожалению, это не помогло.

Comment: @Ted К сожалению, Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за информацию!